# Odd 'return' of password generator function

Tags: python

I'm creating a password generation function for an exercise where I am checking if the user is specifying at least 8 symbols length for the password the be generated while wanting to check if there are 3 wrong input attempts I would just exit the program using return.

I was expecting the return function to STOP everything and not proceed with the following loop afterwards, but that was not the case.

Can you please help me understand why it's happening as it is?

here is the code:

```
    import string
    import random
    attempts = 0

def PasswordGenerator(passwordlenght):
    passwordlenght = int(passwordlenght)
    password= ""
    i = 0

    if passwordlenght < 8:
        print("Password length must be more than 8 symbols !!!")
        global attempts
        attempts += 1

        if attempts <3:
            PasswordGenerator(passwordlenght)
        else:
            return 1    

    while i < passwordlenght:
        if i in range(1,passwordlenght,3):
            password += string.ascii_lowercase[random.randrange(len(string.ascii_lowercase))]
        elif i in range(2, passwordlenght, 3):
            password += string.ascii_uppercase[random.randrange(len(string.ascii_uppercase))]
        elif i in range(3, passwordlenght, 3):
            password += string.digits[random.randrange(len(string.digits))]
        i += 1

    print(password)

PasswordGenerator(5)
```

Comment: It looks like some of the indentation got messed up when putting the code into the question, and that could be affecting things. Please make sure that all lines in the question have the same indentation as in your actual script.

Comment: If the issue isn’t with the indentation I expect it’s related to using recursion instead of a regular looping construct for counting attempts.

Comment: You shouldn't call `PasswordGenerator` from inside the `PasswordGenerator` function. This is called recursion, and it's why you're seeing this behaviour. You return from the inner call, and proceed with the outer call. Rework your code to use a loop instead of trying to use recursion as a `goto`.

Comment: @DanielH I checked the identation, apart from the import statements it seems that it's OK.

Comment: @redneckveganboi Then you should fix the indentation of the import statements in the question.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for the input, FYI if i replace 'return'  with 'sys.exit()' the program finishes just fine ... I'm trying to understand  .... why :)

Comment: You should definitely use plain looping instead of that recursion. But apart from that I don't see anywhere in the code you posted where `passwordlenght` gets changed, so if it's not >= 8, it will never be.

Comment: BTW, you can make your random character selection code a lot simpler by using `random.choice`.

Comment: I just understood the recursion reference :)

Comment: You just explained it to me guys... I can't believe how fast you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening, is that it goes into the 'invalid' section, calls PasswordGenerator again, then finishes the rest of the code. So on the 3rd attempt it will return, NOT generating a password, but will then finish the 2nd attempt, and generate a password, then finish the 1st attempt and generate a password. There are a few ways you can do this, make the while loop at the end an 'else' condition to if passwordlength < 8, or remove the return from the 'else' of if attempts < 3.  The following demonstrates both techniques (though you only need 1)

```
import string
import random
attempts = 0

def PasswordGenerator(passwordlenght):
    passwordlenght = int(passwordlenght)
    password= ""
    i = 0

    if passwordlenght < 8:
        print("Password length must be more than 8 symbols !!!")
        global attempts
        attempts += 1

        if attempts <3:
            PasswordGenerator(passwordlenght)
        return 1
    else:

        while i < passwordlenght:
            if i in range(1,passwordlenght,3):
                password += str ing.ascii_lowercase[random.randrange(len(string.ascii_lowercase))]
            elif i in range(2, passwordlenght, 3):
                password += string.ascii_uppercase[random.randrange(len(string.ascii_uppercase))]
            elif i in range(3, passwordlenght, 3):
                password += string.digits[random.randrange(len(string.digits))]
            i += 1

        print(password)

PasswordGenerator(5)
```

Edit: I am assuming that the way it is currently coded is for testing purposes, otherwise you will only ever pass the originally provided value as the password length, and it will always fail (if less than 8). If that is not what you are doing, you should change that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is with this line:

```
PasswordGenerator(passwordlenght)
```

Your function is recursively calling itself, but since it doesn't `return` the value returned by the recursive call, it will go on to run the rest of the code afterwards.

You could "fix" it by adding a `return`:

```
return PasswordGenerator(passwordlenght)
```

But that's still not a very good solution. For most programs that need to do something a certain number of times, it's much better to use a loop, rather than recursion. Try something like this, which will check three times that indeed the same length is indeed too short:

```
for attempt in range(3):
    if passwordlenght < 8:
        print("Password length must be more than 8 symbols !!!")
    else:
        # put the rest of the code here, including the return
```

Obviously this is a bit silly, since if the length is too short the first time, it will still be too short the second and third times too. I'm not really sure what the point of multiple attempts is for this particular check (it could perhaps make sense for some other checks on a candidate password, but not this one, since the length is provided by the user rather than being random).